# Visual Studio 2017 и подсветка синтаксиса

Tags: c++, visual-studio, синтаксис

Добрый день.

Заметил особенность у Visual Studio 2017. Работаю с транслятором С++. Когда включаешь машину и загружаешь проект в Visual Studio 2017, то подсветка синтаксиса отсутствует. И включается подсветка синтаксиса только после перетрансляции проекта. Это так и надо или глюк? Проекты бывают большие и транслируются по 20 минут и немного напрягает ждать перетрансляции, чтобы включить подсветку синтаксиса.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если нет проблем в коде, то подсветка обычно почти сразу включается. Собирать по 20 минут - это жесть, вам явно следует съоптимизировать сборку.

Comment: Проблем в коде нет, но подсветка включается только при перетрансляции проекта.

Comment: Даже если дать явную команду просканировать файл?